# Is there any way to self create Transformer to run on Coral board?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, transformer-model, google-coral

I want to use a transformer applied on Coral Board edge device. But I cant find any source that apply this.

The transformer can be trained on CloudTPU, but I am not sured the op can operate on Coral board. If I have to self write ops, please tell me how.

Comment: Do you have a Tensorflow Lite model to compile on the edge TPU?  If you are starting with a Keras or Tensorflow model you must first convert it to Tensorflow Lite.  To successfully compile Tensorflow Lite to the edge TPU the model must use these supported operations:  https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations  Unsupported operations will be run on the CPU instead, so if the model uses a lot of unsupported operations then the acceleration will be minimal

Comment: Yes, I understand this. However, I mean how to self create Attention layer as encoder and decoder that can assure the op support, I have tried and failed a lot :)